# My bindings are messed up, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

```
 $(function(){
   $('.update-mod-form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
       data = $.parseJSON(data); 
       console.log(data.success);
       console.log(data);
      if (data.success == true) {
           $('#page').html(data.html);
        }
        else {
        }
   });
 });
```

Do you see any JS bindings Best practices that could correct a bindings problem? This method works, once then After the data.html is added with the .html method, the method doesn't work a second time.

The data.html, generates a class .update-mod-form, which is unbound How can I bind this new class?

I should also note that I have multiple occurrences of this class, is it possible to bind more than one element of a class to a method in this way?

Comment: What does your data look like BEFORE calling $.parseJSON ? Can you do a console.log( data ) and paste it here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#update-mod-form is` is inside `#page`, then after first ajax call, this form (and its bindings) is wiped out. You have to rebind it, or use `live` not `bind`.

ps. you sure the event is `ajax:success` not `ajaxSucces`? And why are you using global event at all?

Comment: Replacing the .bind method with .live worked perfectly. Thank you! I've been working on this problem since lunch!

Answer (score 0):

Remove that "undefined" server-side, otherwise it's not a valid JSON

Comment: Sorry, thats a console.log(data.success) it should return undefined, bc it isn't parsing my json

Comment: @JZ: are you sure your ajax isn' called with getJson or with dataType json?